# Operador logico or

Tags: javascript, operador, booleano

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? En Javascript estoy usando el operador lógico or en :

> Usar el operador logico or en variables 'foo' y 'bar' y asignarle el
>   resultado a la variable disjunction.

Pero no me está resultando; el código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```js
foo = true;
bar = false;

if (foo || bar) {

  disjunction = foo;
} else {
  disjunction = bar;
}
```

Comment: ¿Sabías que ese código se simplifica como `disjunction = foo || bar` y no necesitas un `if`? ¿Podrías explicar un poco mejor lo que te ocurre? Esos dos puntos (`:`) me distraen mucho y no entiendo su significado ni tampoco qué te está saliendo mal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te puedes ahorrar todo el bloque if de la siguiente manera:

```
let disjunction = (foo || bar);
```

Por cierto, si es un ejercicio para practicar, te aconsejo que entiendas bien que hace ese operador:

```js
let foo = "hola";
let bar = "mundo"

console.log(foo || bar);
console.log(bar || foo);
console.log(!!(bar || foo));

console.log(0 || foo);
console.log(foo || 0);
```

Comment: Debí haber editado la pregunta para ver que había una separación de línea :) aunque "me has robado" la respuesta, te llevas mi +1.

Comment: Sí, esos saltos de línea necesarios para crear un nuevo párrafo pueden confundir bastante

Answer (score 2):

Entra al `if` por la variable `foo` y por eso la variable `disjunction` tiene valor `true`

```js
let foo = true,
  bar = false,
  disjunction = undefined;

if (foo || bar) {

  disjunction = foo;
} else {
  disjunction = bar;
}
console.log(disjunction);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score -1):

```
var disjunction=0;
var foo = true;
var bar = false;


Boolean(disjunction); //retorna false por que disjunction vale 0

if (foo==true || bar==false) {

  disjunction = foo;
} else {
  disjunction = bar;
}

alert(disjunction):
```

Comment: Hola Netza. Las respuestas que son solo codigo no son de buena calidad. Has de explicar tu solucion. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo